# With Styled Components and Polish how to include a function as the color?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components and polished for darkening/lightening the colors.

Here's what I have now working:

```
colors = ['#eee', '#ccc', '#ddd'];

const calcBorderColor = ({ currentPosition }) => {
  const color = colors[(currentPosition) % colors.length];
  return color;
};

const Choice = styled.button`
  border-color: ${calcBorderColor};
`;
```

**Where I'm stuck is here:**

```
&:hover {
    border-color: ${darken(0.1, calcBorderColor)};
}
```

That hover styling is error with `Passed an incorrect argument to a color function, please pass a string representation of a color.`

**How can I use polished darken along with the calcBorderColor function?**

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the error when using the `darken` function because it expects a string as second argument and instead you are passing the function declaration of `calcBorderColor` that if you log it, you could see is this:

```
calcBorderColor(_ref) {
    var currentPosition = _ref.currentPosition;

    var color = colors[currentPosition % colors.length];
    return color;
}
```

If you:

```
console.log(typeof calcBorderColor);
```

You will get it is of type *function*.

This come because `polished` library functions are staticly typed by using [Flow](https://flow.org/). And you are not getting an error in the first `border-color` because Styled Components is skipping to render the function declaration, probably leaving the default `border-color` of the button element.

So you need to pass as argument an object with the attribute `currentPosition` in both calls to the `calcBorderColor` function in order to make it usable and avoid that error.

```
const Choice = styled.button`
  border-color: ${calcBorderColor({currentPosition: 1})};

  &:hover {
    border-color: ${darken(0.1, calcBorderColor({ currentPosition: 0}))};
  }
`;
```